# Scroll to a Row in Ngx-datatable programatically

Tags: angular, angular5, tabindex, ngx-datatable

I have a ngx-datatable with `<input>` element in each row. Is there a way to programmatically scroll to a particular row and focus on the `<input>` element.

**Example:**

I have 20 rows in total displaying 10 rows in each page.Based on user actions I want to scroll to 12th row and focus the `<input>` of that row.

Thanks in advance!